# Google Sites - Change a Chart dynamically from a DropDown Selection

Tags: drop-down-menu, charts, dynamically-generated, google-sites

I have inserted a chart from Google Sheets into my Google Sites. However, I can see only the chart. In the Sheets I have a dropdown menu to change the chart based on my selection.

How can I have a dropdown Menu in my Google Site so that the Chart changes dynamically based on my selection from the DropDown Menu?

```
This is the desire result, but I want to have it in Google Site embedded from an Google Sheets.  http://jsfiddle.net/km97cdL3/1/
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Where is the Sheet with the Chart?

Comment: Sorry it was a link that I forgot to include: https://docs.google.com/a/bbva.com/spreadsheets/d/1jUJRnZ29Mv1su1Xd3Z92c6Oi3OepiM1MAXPQMyuDx0E/pubhtml

Comment: Link requires login! May be you need to make screen shot and add link to it or screen shot itself?

Comment: I'm new here and it doesn't let me introduce an image. It is just a pie chart which data changes when selecting an item from a dropdown Menu. I have a dropdow Menu with States: Alabama, Texas and depending on the state I select the data of my Pie Chart changes.

Comment: This is the desire result, but I want to have it in Google Site embedded from an Google Sheets.  http://jsfiddle.net/km97cdL3/1/